# Hiding Divs based on conditions

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have the following HTML structure as an example:

```
<body>


Testing hiding DIVs

<div class="content-1">
<h2>Hello - this is div 1</h2>


<div class="content-2">
<h2>Hello - this os div 2</h2>


</body>
```

I would like to hide div "content-2" only if div"content-1" contains or has content within it.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this using jquery?

Many thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this -  (*you should close your `div` though*)

```
if($('.content-1').contents().length > 0){
  $('.content-2').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('div.content-1:not(:empty)').length) $('div.content-2').hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if($(".content-2").html().length > 0)
    $(".content-1").hide();
```

EDIT- misread this initially-- changed boolean expression.